# Question with bounty ends in a draw

Tags: support, bounty

For this question I added a bounty to draw some attention:

[What is the best way to merge friend lists on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58866/29140)

In its current state, the outcome is undecided.

What will happen with the bounty when no answer is marked as best answered?

PS: perhaps there are people knowledgeable on the topic to make a decisive vote?

Comment: I believe it's split half and half

Comment: @phwd the older answer gets the bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [bounty faq:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/133693)

> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.